# original image get_serving_url via blob

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blob

Is there anyway to get the original image (with same dimensions) with get_serving_url?

If size is not specified it still seems to serve an image scaled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use s=0 you see the original image.

Example: https://lh6.ggpht.com/1HjICy6ju1e2GIg83L0qdliUBmPHUgKV8FP3QGK8Qf2pHVBfwkpO_V38ifAPm-9m20q_3ueZzdRCYQNyDE3pmA695iaLunjE=s0